# How to modify/recreate Html.fromHtml()?

Tags: java, android

I am not that good to understand all the possibility of Java, especially if it's not my code.

So, http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/text/Html.java#Html.fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29 , is it all I need to modify Html.fromHtml() ?

But I don't understand how it's works : Is it a good way to create a new class like Html2 and copy/paste all the code ? When I do that I have some errors that I don't understand :

```
private static class HtmlParser {
        private static final HTMLSchema schema = new HTMLSchema();
    }
```

He tells my Htmlschema cannot be resolved to a type, and to add the class HtmlSchema... but where can i find it ?

And this :

```
return XmlUtils.convertValueToInt(color, -1);
```

> XmlUtils cannot be resolved.

The rest of the errors have been solved with the help of Eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> He tells my Htmlschema cannot be resolved to a type, and to add the class HtmlSchema... but where can i find it ?

```
import org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.HTMLSchema;
```

`HTMLSchema` is from TagSoup, a JAR used inside of Android's frameworks but not exposed through the Android SDK.

> XmlUtils cannot be resolved.

```
import com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils;
```

`XmlUtils` is a class from the Android firmware, not exposed through the Android SDK.

Comment: Thank you sir. So the idea to create a new class Html() is good ?

Comment: @Shinao: The idea of creating a better HTML->`Spanned` converter is good. Given the limitations you encountered, I am skeptical that trying to use the existing `android.text.Html` class as a basis will work well. You might be better served using it as inspiration for your own implementation.

Comment: May I ask if you were able to successfully do this? I'm really having a hard time doing the same thing. :|